# Grouping Categories of Icons in Windows 10 Taskbar

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, icons

I have lots of icons in my task-bar - they're all necessary, because monitor real estate is at a premium and I need that sliver of visible desktop for things other than launch icons.

*What I'm looking to do is group certain icons into a category* - specifically, one icon for Microsoft Office and another for the Adobe suite that, when clicked, will expand to show launch icons for the individual programs in each category.

I just installed Adobe, and have no chance of fitting all those programs into my taskbar without this grouping function.  As a last resort, I could always switch to small-size icons, but I'm hoping to avoid that because I'm as blind as the proverbial bat.

It could be I'm searching for the wrong things and the answer is obvious.

Comment: Yes!  This is exactly what I'm after!  And $10 is a better price than you can shake a stick at.  Bless you!

Comment: Cool, would you think it's appropriate if I made my comment an answer?

Comment: Please do!  You completely solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you consider a third-party product? Something like ObjectDock by StarDock can help you. This request isn't available natively within Windows.

Answer (score 3):

For Windows 10, try the program Bins (by 1UP Industries). At the time of writing, it is $5. Bins does not make you use a separate dock. You can drag icons on your taskbar over each other to create bins. I have no affiliation with the program, other than I am a user that finds it useful. It gives the taskbar a functionality that it should already have.

http://www.1upindustries.com/bins/

[image]